# OpenAI Gym Jupyter Notebook NameError Traceback (most recent call last)

Tags: openai-gym

I wanted to start with Cartpole. Whenever I try to test any of my variable like `enviroment_name`

```
NameError Traceback (most recent call last) Cell In[7], line 1 ----> 1 enviroment_name
NameError: name 'enviroment_name' is not defined.
```

Likewise, if I try `env.action_space.sample()`, I get

```
NameError Traceback (most recent call last) Cell In[12], line 1 ----> 1 env.action_space.sample() 
NameError: name 'env' is not defined.` And so on.
```

Please guide me.

Also, I want to understand this first, before moving to **Network Attack Simulator (NASim)** which also similar OpenAI gym.

I was expecting an output on each of my defined variable. Before moving further. TIA